# Form all possible strings in 2 level lists

Tags: python

I have a two-level list like this :

```
[['Demonstrative-Pronoun', 'Personal-Pronoun', 'Adjective', 'Noun', 'Noun', 'Indefinite-Pronouns'], ['Verb', 'Adjective', 'Adverb', 'Noun', 'Noun'], ['Verb', 'Verb', 'Verb', 'Verb', 'Adjective', 'Noun', 'Noun', 'Verb'], ['Verb', 'Verb', 'Verb', 'Verb', 'Verb', 'Verb', 'Noun']]
```

I want to form all possible strings from these lists like :

1. Demonstrative-Pronoun Verb Verb Verb
2. Demonstrative-Pronoun Adjective Verb Verb
   and so on

Is there a quicker way in python to do this or any quick way to? This list is hard-coded but it may actually contain any number of elements and sub-elements

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `itertools.product` to basically make a bunch of nested `for` loops:

```
import itertools

items = [...]

for grouping in itertools.product(*items):
    print ' '.join(grouping)
```

This'll give you all 1680 combinations.

*From Comments*: "You could replace items with map(set, items) and it'll remove the duplicates. That drops the count to 120."

Comment: thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. I may now need something to reduce that list size. This count is too much for such a small list. But that's part of another question, i guess ;) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AkshatGoel: You could replace `items` with `map(set, items)` and it'll remove the duplicates. That drops the count to 120.

Comment: Thanks! :) I will add that part to answer itself :)